# Find Mystery Nums M/N

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am pretty sure I got this right just want to make sure though... *In the following code, we have omitted the definitions of constants M and N*
here are the two functions in question arith and optarith:

```
#define M /* Mystery number 1 */
#define N /* Mystery number 2 */

unsigned int arith(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    unsigned int result = 0;
    result = x * M + y/N;
    return result;
}
```

*We compiled this code for particular values of M and N. The compiler optimized the multiplication and
division. The following is a translation of the generated machine code back into* C:

```
unsigned int optarith(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    unsigned int t = 3 * x;
    x <<= 6;
    x -= 2 * t;
    y >>= 4;
    y = y/3;
    return x + y;
}
```

so here's my work 
so to find value M for the operation M * x

```
x <<= 6; // same as  x = x * 64
x-= 2 * t; //same as x = x - 2 * (3 * x)
```

**so basically x = 64x - 6x which is just 58x therefore M = 58**

and to find the value N for operation y/N

```
y >>= 4;  same as y = y/16;
y = y/3; same as y = (y/16)/3;
```

**that makes y/48 so N = 48**

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Stackoverflow can help with programming questions, but not evaluate code for correctness.  If you have a specific question, feel free to ask, but otherwise this question may be flagged.

Comment: @roelofs this isn't code that was made by me, it was a practice exam question that I worked on.  And i have to find the values of M and N.  There is no coding just doing some math.

Comment: I think you could turn this from something which looks like a "review please" (off-topic here) into a question on equivalence of operations. In order to demonstrate some research of your own, you could show the output of some experiments you did. E.g. use both versions in a test sequence of several values for both inputs and show  whether the results of both versions are always identical. The sentence which would have e.g. me understand your question quicker might be "The return value for both versions should of course be identical for all possible input."

Comment: @Yunnosch is correct - you will have to adapt the question, otherwise it's off topic both for being a review question, as well as being math related, and will likely be flagged and removed as such.